# Crouton environment does not free memory after exiting program?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, crouton-os

I am new to using Crouton. I am trying to use it for some C programming practice in a linux environment. Anytime I run a program that uses malloc(), I get a memory leak error for x amount of bytes. The memory leak error dissipates when I explicitly free the allocated memory. Is this a Crouton issue or a Ubuntu issue overall?

Is there any way to fix it so that I do not have to explicitly free allocated space every time? I understand the free()ing is good coding practice and whatnot, but I was just wondering if there was a way so that allocated memory is automatically free'd after exiting.

Comment: Why do you want to move away from the *way we do things* - it's your call to free them and you are doing it. That's how it should be. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Allocated memory ceases to exist after the process exits since it is allocated in the process address space only and that address space ceases to exist.

Comment: I understand that explicitly freeing is the best practice. I was just wondering why Crouton didn't automatically do it for you. I will definitely use free in the future as it is usually a good countermeasure to memory leaks as your program gets larger and more complicated.

Comment: What is reporting a memory leak error? Something compiled into your program that prints a report when the program is exiting? A debugger or an IDE? Something in Crouton? An external program you run?

Comment: @coderredoc: If a program is exiting, what benefit is there is freeing its memory? Freeing memory within the process merely alters data structures that will vanish when the operating system releases the memory the process used. The end result of a process exiting with all memory freed is the same as the end result of a processing exiting without all memory freed, so expending time to free memory is a waste of computing time. (Memory must be freed in ongoing processes while a program continues running, but the final termination does not have any need to free memory.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Good practice it is and it helps in extending the program at later stage in a big system without risking the sudden arrival of memory leaks. But yes I get your point. There is waste of computing time. But most of the time - it leads to unmanaged memory handling - that calls for Mem leak.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (and most modern multi-tasked OSes) when a process is exiting (or is terminated, e.g. by a signal) all its resources are released by the OS kernel, including its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

So it is certainly possible to forget to `free`  heap memory before exiting, and many (but not all) programs are doing so.

If you are developing an application, you might still want to properly `free` every dynamically allocated memory zone when exiting. This facilitates the use of memory leak detecting tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (but take some development efforts, and even some run time).

Comment: The OP says a memory leak error is reported. If this were a simple case of running a program, the program exits, and the operating system tears down its memory, there would be no memory leak report. Something additional is happening, and we ought to understand that before answering.

Answer (score 1):

`C` is a [Manual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management) language, it means you need to release memories that you have allocated manually in contrast with [Garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). You may use functions such as `atexit()` to facilitate memory deallocation process at program exit, but I don't suggest this personally as a good programming practice. If you are programming with `C` programming language, you should learn to deallocate memory with `free()`.